# Is there any way to invoke a router from Processor in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a list of message and want to process one by one to a router. So is there any way i don't want to a pass a whole list of message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create a producer template:

```
@Autowired
ProducerTemplate template;
```

and then use the send method to send whatever data you want to your route:

```
template.sendBody("direct:start", "body");
```